# How to find the power series expansion that converges to Fresnel integral?

Tags: integration, power-series, taylor-expansion

Fresnel integral is $S(x)=\int_{0}^x{\sin(t^2)\,dt}$.

I'm trying to see how the [power series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) for the integral is found , I have to tried to use Taylor Series for expanding $\sin(t^2)$ but i couldn't see a pattern in the derivations.

Comment: Did you try integrating the power series expansion for $\sin x^2$ term by term?  It does have an infinite radius of convergence and is uniformly convergent on any closed interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taylor gives
$$
\sin(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}t^{2n+1}
$$
applied at $t^2$:
$$
\sin(t^2) =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}t^{4n+2}
$$
Integrated over $t$ from $0$ to $x$:
$$
\int\limits_0^x \sin(t^2) \, dt = 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!(4n+3)}x^{4n+3}
$$

Comment: Maybe some explanations about the values of t where the series of sinus converges and why you can integrate term  by term the series would be welcomed The nature of the question leads to think user3133165 is not familiar with that.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$
\int_0^x\sin( t^2) dt=\frac12\int_0^{x^2}\sin y\frac{dy}{\sqrt y}
=\frac12\int_0^{x^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{y^{2n+1/2}}{(2n+1)!}dy.
$$
The subsequent computation is obvious.

Comment: Why is x changed to $x^2$, and how was the series computed?

Comment: $y=t^2$, so the integration limits are changed appropriately. The series is the standard Taylor series for the sine multiplied by $y^{-1/2}$.